# How to connect two vertices?

Tags: vertices

I forgot how to connect two vertices.

[image]

The documentation says I need to press "J" but nothing happens.

Comment: J is not related to this case. It works only splitting existing geometry (like Knife) and doesn't generate any new one

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out again... you have to press <kbd>F</kbd>.

Comment: Orly? No kidding...

Comment: Yes, I hate it when I forget something this simple if I abandon blender for a long time... even though I know blender for centuries lol

Comment: How many years is 'centuries'? I go back to 2000/2001

Comment: There indeed aren't any questions here on BSE on questions like "how to create edge" or "face" or stuff because they are very basic. This can be quickly found in [blender manual](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/basics/make_face_edge.html)

Comment: @MrZak, I even searched the manual but did not found it.

Comment: Use [search terms](https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20manual%20how%20create%20face) making blender manual be the top priority, vary the words. That's most general and the best way to get any result